# python - nltk join the results

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

How do I join these results into a text? I tried " ".join() function, it doesn't work well. Are there any other ways to join the results from nltk library? Thanks!

```
import nltk 
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer 
ps = PorterStemmer()

data_list = ['the gamers playing games','higher scores','sports']
for words in data_list:
    words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(words)
    for w in words:
        print(ps.stem(w))
```

current results:

```
the
gamer
play
game
higher
score
sport
```

Final results into a list:

```
['the gamer play game',
 'higher score',
 'sport']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
data_list = ['the gamers playing games','higher scores','sports']
result =[' '.join([ps.stem(w) for w in nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(words)])    
     for words in data_list]
```